# Compact formula for Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I need help with the Taylor exansion in a neighborhood $0$ of
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}.$$
I started evaluating the first terms which should be
$$1+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{3}{8}x^2 +\frac{5}{16}x^3+...$$
but, if possible, I need a compact formula (I guess some factorial would be involved).

Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cf. [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: Let $z=-x$ and use 
$$(1+z)^p=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{\Gamma(p-k+1)}\frac{z^k}{k!}$$

Comment: @K.defaoite Do you think is a good idea to bring up the Gamma function to someone who is struggling with something so basic as the Taylor series of that function?